# How to resolve No module named 'nltk.translate.meteor_score' on google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nlp, nltk, google-colaboratory

[No module named 'nltk.translate.meteor_score'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FUZQ.png)

Comment: The error message says "No module named blah blah."  Figure out why colab thinks that module doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I am unable to understand why colab is saying this?
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `!pip install -U nltk`
because the preinstalled nltk version on Colab is 3.2.5 and the last available is 3.5

It works for me

Comment: Works spot on. It's just installing the latest version of nltk

Answer (score 0):

The meteor_score is not available in the version of nltk that got installed.
.
You have to uninstall it and install the version which has meteor_score function.

```
# Uninstall the previous installed nltk library
!pip install -U nltk

# This upgraded nltkto version 3.5 in which meteor_score is there.
!pip install nltk==3.5
```